# ModalContentPresenter with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, caliburn.micro, c#-5.0

I am trying to find ways to properly show non-window based modal dialogs (ie. they cover existing part of the window and are shown on top of that content in a modal way - the covered part is not accessible). The application is built in .net 4.5 on top of the caliburn.micro framework 1.5.2 and uses MefBootstrapper (based on http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper).

The simple solution (overlapping controls in the xaml stack) does not cover all issues, like keyboard focus and navigation.

I have found the ModalContentPresenter class, derived from FrameworkElement, and presented at http://programmingwithpassion.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/displaying-modal-content-in-wpf/ which seems to handle most of the possible issues with modal dialogs.

Unfortunately, the window does not show any content. Based on my research it seems like the code conventions are not working for controls defined as children of the ModalContentPresenter. Unfortunately, I failed to find the right place to look in the caliburn.micro source code and/or documentation.

Example (without ModelContentPresenter, working):

```
<Window>
    <TextBlock x:Name="SomeName"/>
</Window>
```

Example (with ModelContentPresenter, not working):

```
<Window>
    <c:ModelContentPresenter isModal="False">
        <TextBlock x:Name="SomeName"/>
    </c:ModelContentPresenter>
</Window>
```

What I need to do to get the code conventions working with the ModelContentPresenter, or do you have a better solution?

Comment: Have you checked the sample application called HelloScreens that is part of the [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) in the documentation. The author implemented that in nice way and as far as i can tell it works with navigation and focus.

Comment: The screens/conductors etc. are supposed for cases when there is just one single screen visited at each time (from that particular stack). 

This contrasts to my case, when I would like to have the original screen still visible while the modal dialog is shown (the original screen is be slightly darkened as long as a modal dialog is shown). As such, I do not see the sample application useful.

Yes, they are useful for the part "show the current screen" and "show the most recent modal dialog", but not for "show the current screen and modal dialog at the same time on the same place".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work. It's a slightly modified version of the sample code found at http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/432271.

```
        BindingScope.AddChildResolver(
            type => type == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter),
            control =>
            {
                var result = new List<DependencyObject>();

                var typedControl = control as System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter;
                if (typedControl != null)
                {
                    if (typedControl.Content is DependencyObject)
                    {
                        result.Add(typedControl.Content as DependencyObject);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            });
```

Note: The ModalContentPresenter is somehow understood by the current Caliburn.Micro's FindNamedDescendants (called as part of the GetNamedElements func, which Sniffer pointed me to). As a result, the ModalContentPresenter could not be cought by this way, but its Content and ModalContent property can; that's why the test is agains the ContentPresenter type.